# what is the purpose of having two constructor, one calling super() and another with argument of its own object

Tags: java

```
public class SuperClassTest {


    private  int id;

    SuperClassTest(){
    super();
    }

    public SuperClassTest(SuperClassTest sct){


    this.id=sct.id;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SUPERCLASS ID" + id;
    }

}
```

Comment: if you don't write any statement in no-arg constructor, compiler will put `super();` statement. its simply to call Object class constructor.

Comment: At some point in time, did this class have a parent that wasn't `Object`?

Comment: @Makoto    Yes another class maintain has a relationship with this class as "SuperClassTest  sct = new SuperClassTest()"

Comment: ...No.  You're just instantiating the `SuperClassTest` now.  There's nothing about that that says `public class SuperClassTest extends _____`.

Comment: No not extend any other class

Answer (score 2):

Calling super in the first case is *useless*. In fact unless you extend a class, (all classes implicitly extend Object.) calling `super()` will be useless.

```
 SuperClassTest(){
   super();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second constructor, the one that's taking an argument of its own type, is a *copy constructor*. It's initializing the *new* object to the same state as that of the object being passed to it.

Now, since you've defined this constructor, the *compiler* will not provide a *default no-args constuctor* for your *class* anymore. This is the reason why you have to specify the `SuperClassTest()` constructor explicitly now.

However, providing an explicit call to `super();` is unnecessary here because the *compiler* would have added that automatically had it been missing. You specify a `super` constructor call when the parent class is expecting some constructor arguments. The compiler then cannot make a call on your behalf because it cannot guess what values should be passed to the `super` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If a constructor begins with an explicit invocation of a superclass constructor

`( a super() invocation)`, its constructor will invoke the corresponding superclass constructor.

For example, if a constructor begins with an explicit invocation of the "super(int, String) constructor," the corresponding constructor will begin by invoking the superclass's "(int, String)" constructor.

If a constructor does not begin with an explicit this() or super() invocation, the corresponding constructor will invoke the superclass's no-arg constructor by default.